# forceServerObjectId option in MongoDb nodejs driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When `forceServerObjectId` option should be used?

From what I could find you can set this option to `true` if you don't want `_id` to be returned for your document.

1. What is the benefit of `forceServerObjectId`?
2. Is there a chance that the client generates ObjectId that already
   exists in the database?